# java pyramid with multiple of 2 not working

Tags: java, for-loop, pyramid

I am suppose to create a pyramid and multiply each number by two until it reach the middle then divide by two such as shown in example below.

[image: the right pyramid]

However after writing my code I am unable to have the numbers double (i*2) then once it reaches the center it divides by two until the it becomes `1`

My output:

[image: my code that doesn't come out right]

```
 package question5;

 public class Pyramid {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 5;
    int rowCount = 1;

    System.out.println("Here Is Your Pyramid");

    //Implementing the logic

    for (int i = x; i > 0; i--)
    {
        //Printing i*2 spaces at the beginning of each row

        for (int j = 1; j <= i*2; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        //Printing j value where j value will be from 1 to rowCount

        for (int j = 1; j <= rowCount; j++)             
        {
        System.out.print(j+" ");
        }

        //Printing j value where j value will be from rowCount-1 to 1

        for (int j = rowCount-1; j >= 1; j--)
        {                    
        System.out.print(j+" ");             
        }                          

        System.out.println();

        //Incrementing the rowCount

        rowCount++;
    }
}
}
```

[this is the weird output of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qfF1.png)

Comment: This seems like you have a sequence of integers, and you need to map them onto a geometric sequence. Once you find the formula, your program is otherwise correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working... You can use math.pow method.

```
public class test {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;
        int rowCount = 1;

        System.out.println("Here Is Your Pyramid");
        //Implementing the logic

        for (int i = x; i > 0; i--)
        {
            //Printing i*2 spaces at the beginning of each row
            for (int j = 1; j <= i*2; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            //Printing j value where j value will be from 1 to rowCount

            for (int j = 0; j <= rowCount-1; j++)             
            {
            System.out.printf("%2d", (int)Math.pow(2, j));  
            }

            //Printing j value where j value will be from rowCount-1 to 1

            for (int j = rowCount-1; j >= 1; j--)
            {                    
            System.out.printf("%2d", (int)Math.pow(2, j-1));
            }                          

            System.out.println();

            //Incrementing the rowCount

            rowCount++;

        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're outputting `j`, a number from `1` to `5`. You want to output **2<sup>j-1</sup>** instead, which is easy: `1 << (j - 1)`.

You also need to right-adjust the number. Your print statement then becomes:

```
System.out.printf("%4d", 1 << (j - 1));
```

Comment: do you want me to put in for loop

Comment: No, just replace the two `System.out.print(j+" ");`

Comment: ok thanks, ill do that right now, i put a picture to the code and it looks really weird?

Comment: i put a picture to the code and it looks really weird?